# Background image for li

Tags: html, css

I'm using a background image for a `< li >` element that will be used as a bullet point, but there is one problem: if one item of the list (I mean `< li >`) contains big text, a long sentence for instance, which can be shown on the page in 2-3 lines (rows), so then the bullet point is placed on the middle of this 2-3 lines and it looks awful.

When I have just one line of text, then everything looks perfectly.

Well my problem ist as follows, I need to place it indirectly before the 1st line, at the beginning!

This is my code.

```
.has-textlist ul li {
    background: url("../images/bullet.png");
    background-position:  0% 50%;
    background-size: 7px 5.5px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You're explicitly vertically centering the image (50%), try something like `background: url("../images/bullet.png") top left no-repeat;` instead.

Comment: right after background setting? I mean  top left no-repeat + top left no-repeat; ?? It doesnt work.

Comment: BenM : I tried but it doesnt make any sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**background-position** is the answer

`background-position:  0 0;`

up to you whatever number and setting you please.

I will be nice and make a fiddle for you:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/2LybX/1/)

Comment: But then they start flying up, therefore i am using vertical correction. background-position setting is already used.

Comment: Hence why you change the 0 to -whateeverpx like so `background-position: 0 -5px;`

Comment: If I dont change it the bullet points are going up, have no idea why, and with 50% only I can adjust them correctly.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know that it should work, cause I did everything as in your code first time, but it doesnt work properly. Maybe it happens in fact of the CSS Foundation Framework, which I am using or maybe some paddings are doing it in the parent class, anyway the problem is somewhere in parent class i suppose. Thanks for your code. Your reply was really usefull cause now I know that my first settings were right. Will try to fix the problem.

Comment: I missed this Setting in your code - no-repeat 0 6px. Now I included them and everything looks really perfect! Thank you! U solved my problem for 100%!

Comment: Awesome glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you can customize your List Bullet Point Image?
Use this property:

```
ul { list-style-image:url('../images/bullet.png');}
```

For your purposes, I guess it will handle.

Comment: it doesnt allow to change the size on the fly, therefore i used background.